# How to get the conditional probability of $X|Y\sim Y N(0,\sigma_1^2)+(1-Y) N(0,\sigma_2^2)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If we have a random variable $Y\sim Ber(p)$ and
$$X|Y\sim Y N(0,\sigma_1^2)+(1-Y)N(0,\sigma_2^2)$$

How to get $f(x|y)$ proportion to the product of two normal distribution?

Is it just the sum of two normal distributions?
The expectation of $X|Y$ is $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)=0$. Do we have $ Var(X|Y)=Y^2\sigma_1^2+(1-Y)^2\sigma_2^2$

Comment: Don't understand your question. You already have the distribution, why ask again?
$$ X|Y\sim Y N(0,\sigma_1^2)+(1-Y)N(0,\sigma_2^2) $$
Also $\text{var}(X|Y)=Y(\sigma_1^2-\sigma_2^2) + \sigma_2^2$.

Note that $\text{var}(X|Y)$ is a random variable, but $Var(YZ_1)+Var((1-Y)Z_2)$ is a number.

Comment: @NeatMath I just want to write $X|Y$ as a Normal$(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Why the Var(X|Y) is $Y(\sigma_1^2-\sigma_2^2)+\sigma_2^2$ but not $Y^2\sigma_1^2+(1-Y)^2\sigma_2^2$? Is it just sum of two normal distributions, right?

Comment: @NeatMath Can we write $X|Y$ as the product of two normal distribution?

Comment: @NeatMath Is not this one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables?

Comment: @NeatMath Why $Y^2\sigma_1^2+(1-Y)^2\sigma_2^2$ is the same as yours?

Comment: Because $Y$ is either 0 or 1. No it's not the product of two normal distribution. It's a mixture of normal. See the Wiki link I provided earlier.

Comment: @NeatMath Is f(x|y) proportion to the product of two normals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting $Z_i\sim N(0;\sigma_i^2)$ and assuming independence between $Z_1$,$Z_2$ and $Y$,

your conditional density is a mixture of the two gaussian densities

$$f_{X|Y=y}(t)=yf_{Z_1}(t) +(1-y)f_{Z_2}(t)$$

---

The marginal distribution is:

$$f_X(x)=\frac{p}{\sigma_1\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma_1^2}}+\frac{1-p}{\sigma_2\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma_2^2}}$$

Comment: I mean can we get the prior of $f(x|y)\propto?$ up to a constant?

Comment: @Lucas : see my edits

Comment: Thanks. But why change $Y$ into $p$? Since $Y$ is known in this conditional probability.

Comment: @Lucas :sorry it's an obvoius typo, $p$ and $1-p$ are in the marginal density

Comment: Can $f_{X|Y=y}(t)=yf_{Z_1}(t) +(1-y)f_{Z_2}(t)$ be rewritten as $(f_{Z_1}(t)) ^y(f_{Z_2}(t))^{1-y}$?

Comment: @Lucas : yes you can. $y=\{0;1\}$ thus $f_{X|Y=0}=f_{Z_2}$ and $f_{X|Y=1}=f_{Z_1}$. Same result with both notations

Answer (score 1):

The question is not 100% clear so I will get everything in one place.

Conditional distribution of $X|Y$ is normal whose parameter depends on $Y$, with density function
$$
f_{X|Y}(x|y) = y \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_1}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma_1^2}\right) + (1-y) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_2}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma_2^2}\right), x \in (-\infty, \infty), y \in \{0,1\}
$$

Marginal distribution of $X$ is a mixture distribution with density
$$f_X(x) = p \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_1}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma_1^2}\right) + (1-p) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_2}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma_2^2}\right), x \in (-\infty, \infty)$$

Conditional variance of $X|Y$is a function of $Y$:
$$
\text{var}(X|Y) = Y\sigma_1^2 + (1-Y) \sigma_2^2
$$
Marginal variance of $X$ is a number:
$$
\text{var}(X) = p\sigma_1^2 + (1-p) \sigma_2^2.
$$

Comment: Thanks. But is it $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma_1^2}}$?

Comment: Yes my bad. Fixed.